# Which GUI builder can be used for 2D game user interface modeling?

Tags: java, user-interface, ide, 2d

I am creating 2D games, where I have lots of background wallpaper for 1024x768 resolution. And I have dozens of icons to place.

I have tried Windows Builder pro + JFormDesigner but they are mostly suitable to create forms/data entry like applications/business logic, not especially 2D graphics with style.

For Java Game development which GUI builders are out there (free/nonfree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot many of them, you can use Nifty GUI, http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/.

Comment: I agree, good choice, thought somewhat missing docs. Still if you learn it.. it allows to do complex things easy. If you have any specific questions - contact me, I've got quite a bit experience in it.